# How to check if a table exists in sqlite3 nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I am using Express for building an application, and on one endpoint, I have a table in sqlite3 being generated through this code

```
    db.serialize(() => {
        db.prepare(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${req.body.tablename}(id TEXT)`).run().finalize();
        db.close();
    });
```

and then I have another endpoint that checks if the table exists using this code

```
 db.get(`SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?`, req.param.name, (err, row) => {
        console.log(row) 
 });
```

But row comes out as undefined when I am 100% sure that the table was created and exists.

Comment: Check `PRAGMA schema.table_info(table-name);` [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info). If table exists you'll obtain at least one record.

Answer (score 2):

change your code to this one:

```js
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('guy.sqlite'); //':memory:'

db.serialize(() => {
    db.prepare(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tb1 (id TEXT)`).run().finalize();

    db.get(`SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?`, 'tb1', (err, row) => {
        console.log(row)
    });

    db.close();
});
```